# Need the WinForm application to communicate with Nexus 7 -- without a proper NFC reader

Tags: java, c#, android, nfc, nexus-7

I have created a winform app on c#. I want this app to read/write NFC tags and display the content on the form. Is it possible? Or will I have to build the app on JAVA? I am confused. Please suggest. 
I do not have a proper NFC reader and want my Nexus to act like a reader and writer here. 
I understand I will have to create another application for my Nexus which sends an acknowledgement to the desktop application. Is that correct? That will mean that the desktop app (C#) will need to talk to Android app (JAVA)?
OS: Windows 8.1
Platform: C#.Net

Please ask me for any more information on this if you think this data is insufficient to answer.
Thanks!

Comment: Begin reading NFC on the device. Open some sort of network socket or other communication.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can absolutely do that as long as your device has the NFC hardware. (I believe the Nexus 7 does)

What you may want to do is to send and receive NFC data in the form of NDEF messages.

You need to add manifest permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
```

The Android operating system can help you to handle NFC data:

> Android provides a special tag dispatch system that analyzes scanned
>   NFC tags, parses them, and tries to locate applications that are
>   interested in the scanned data. It does this by:
>
> 1. Parsing the NFC tag and figuring out the MIME type or a URI that identifies the data payload in the tag.
> 2. Encapsulating the MIME type or URI and the payload into an intent. These first two steps are
>      described in How NFC tags are mapped to MIME types and URIs.
> 3. Starts an activity based on the intent. This is described in How NFC Tags are
>      Dispatched to Applications.

See [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc.html).

Comment: It's a Nexus 7 (the tablet) rather than nexus 5, but the Nexus 7 does indeed have NFC.

Comment: Thanks! Will I have to create another application for my Nexus which can send me an acknowledgement on the latop about the tag being written or how is it done?

Comment: You can integrate such functionality into an existing app you are working on. But if you don't have anything, yes, you might need to make an app.

Comment: Have reworded the question. Please have a look at it again.